# PropertyNotWritableException in JSF, even though property is writeable

Tags: java, jsf

I was wondering if you could help me debug one issue that we're having. We're getting the following error on a JSF page:

```
PropertyNotWritableException: /resources/al/template.xhtml @96,112 value="#{cc.attrs.value.editedProperty.value}": The class 'org.company.tpl.template.TemplateString' does not have a writable property 'value'.
```

This is caused by this line in the view:

```
<p:column><p:inputText id="property-value" value="#{cc.attrs.value.editedProperty.value}"/></p:column>
```

As you can see, the property is writeable in the class:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("String")
public class TemplateString extends TemplateProperty {
    @Column(name = "STRING_VALUE")
    private String value;

    // ...

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    // ...
}
```

The weirdest thing is, this error happens only on production, but not in the lab. Both production and lab are running Glassfish 3.1.2.2. In the lab, all works perfectly.

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: There are two `value` references in your EL expression so perhaps it is the composite component attribute named `value` that does not have a setter?

Answer (score 3):

the problem lies in inheritance.

probably your TemplateProperty class is implemented like:

```
public class TemplateProperty {
    public Object getValue() {
        return some_value;
    }
    ...
}
```

so el tries to read `Object getValue()` and tries to write `void setValue(Object obj)` which is not present.

i think this is a bug, and i don't know a workaround yet...